# External captive portal using HotSpot service on Ruckus ZoneDirectory ZD3050

Tags: captiveportal, ruckus-api

I try to create an external captive portal using HotSpot service on Ruckus ZoneDirectory ZD3050 (v10.1.2.0 build 210). How to authenticate clients? I have a web page as a portal, I have my custom authorization flow, but I don't know how to authenticate clients in ZoneDirectory (allow access to WiFi) after successful login.

Comment: Explain what exactly "Ruckus ZoneDirectory ZD3050" is.

Comment: Zone Director – Ruckus ZoneDirector controllers feature a highly-intuitive Web user interface to make configuration and administration of the entire WLAN a breeze. It delivers a bunch of wireless LAN features not found in any other centrally-managed systems. They include capabilities like automatic traffic redirection, adaptive wireless meshing, rogue AP detection and advanced Wi-Fi security features and extensive authentication support. Ruckus ZoneDirector is widely-considered the simplest, most straightforward centralized WLAN software solution there is.

Comment: Thank you. So, add the method that you tried to create an external captive portal using HotSpot service on this device on the body of the question.

Comment: I mean, how did you config Hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on how to do this.

https://webresources.ruckuswireless.com/pdf/appnotes/appnote-wispr.pdf